# Rotating a PPM Image 90 degrees

Tags: rotation, ppm

I need help rotating a PPM image in C. The rotate function is supposed to rotate the image of a previously read in PPM image 90 degrees to the right. The code will be posted below. I need help with the rotate() function.

The signature of the function is:

```
void rotate(pixel_t *image, int x, int y)
```

X is the width of the image and Y is the height.

Here is a look at how I accomplished some other PPM manipulations in this program:

```
void grayscale(pixel_t *image, int x, int y)
{
    int i, average = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < x*y; i++)
    {
        average = (image[i].r + image[i].g + image[i].b) / 3;
        printf("%c%c%c", average, average, average);
    }
}

void flipImage(pixel_t *image, int x, int y)
{
    int r, c, i;
    for (c = y-1; c >= 0; c--)
    {
        for (r = 0; r < x; r++)
        {
            i = (c * x) + r;
            printf("%c%c%c", image[i].r, image[i].g, image[i].b);
        }
    }
}
```

This is what I have so far:

```
void rotate(pixel_t *image, int x, int y)
{
    int r, c;
    for (r = 0; r < x; r++)
    {
         for (c = 0; c < y; r++)
         {
             printf("%c%c%c", image[c].r, image[c].g, image[c].b);
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you need to see the entire program, let me know.

Comment: What do you have so far for the rotate function?

Comment: Also, is your image square or do you need to deal with unequal height and width dimensions?

Comment: I posted above what I have so far. I'm not even sure if it is on the right track?